# BIG Paypal shipping issue

Tags: html, paypal

I am currently using Paypal for my little shop. The problem I have been dealing with is that the shipping fee for each item is 5 USD. However, for example,  when a customer buy 3 pieces for an item, the shipping fee is still 5 USD. It doesn't increase automatically to 15 USD.

So, is there a way that I can fix the problem? So that I don't have to pay the shipping fee for the customers every time they buy more than a piece from each item.

The code that Paypal gave me since the beginning is

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.000">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted">
```

So, if you have an idea how to solve this issue, please feel free to let me know.

Thank you so much.

K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increment the shipping with the addition of each quantity , you need to add one more variable along with the above variables and that should do it :

```
<input type="hidden" name="shipping2" value="5.00">
```

Comment: WOW. Thank you so much Eshan for your guide. It's working.

Thank you again.